# Unity Network No sound on other clients

Tags: unity, c#, sound, unity-networking

I'm trying to play sound on other clients, so they could hear gunfire in the distance, but sound only works for the shooter. Here's my code:

```
    void Update()
    {
        ***

        if (Input.GetButton("Fire1"))
        {
            CmdFireWeapon(this.gameObject);
        }

        ***
    }

    [Command]
    void CmdFireWeapon(GameObject plr)
    {
       ***        

        if (!plr.GetComponent<AudioSource>().isPlaying)
            RpcPlayWeapon(plr);

       ***
    }

    [ClientRpc]
    void RpcPlayWeapon(GameObject plr)
    {
        plr.GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
    }
```

I'm using 3D Spatial Blend, but there's no sound even with volume == 1 across all distance. Also tried with and without `if(isPlaying)` - no progress. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out. Player Prefab on other clients spawned without clip (it is loaded in its script). So I needed to load it first then play it. And I need to keep loading, because clip changes with different weapon.

```
[ClientRpc]
    void RpcPlayWeapon(GameObject plr)
    {
            plr.GetComponent<AudioSource>().clip = 
                    plr.GetComponent<PlrController>().curWeapon.shotAudio;
            plr.GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
    }
```